# SUM time values in related table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in a MySQL database, events and appointments.  Each appointment has a field event_id, a start_time and an end_time column.

I'm trying to set up a query which will give me the event ids with their total amount of appointment time in minutes.  For example, if an event has two appointments with the following details:

1. Starts at 10:00:00, Finishes at 11:30:00
2. Starts at 12:30:00, Finishes at 13:15:00

Then the appointments column for the event would read 135.

I know how to get a simple count of the appointments but I'm a bit stuck when it comes to working out the time.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT
events.id AS event_id,
(SELECT COUNT(id) FROM appointments WHERE event_id = events.id) AS appointment_count
FROM events
```

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: If Shafeeq's solution has solved your problem, consider marking it as the accepted answer. Otherwise, consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
SELECT e.name, ap.event_id,
sum((TIME_TO_SEC(end_time) - TIME_TO_SEC(start_time))/60) AS dif
FROM events e LEFT JOIN appointment ap ON e.id = ap.event_id
GROUP BY e.name, ap.event_id
ORDER BY 2;
```

**[Example..](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27d112/3/0)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT A.*,count(B.*) as count
FROM table_event A
JOIN table_appointment B ON A.event_id = B.event_id
GROUP BY B.event_id
```